# wc -m in linux excess 1 value

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wc

```
md5sum file.png | awk '{print $1}' | wc -m
```

I get: `33`
I expect it will return `32` as the length of md5 hash. After read man page and googling I still didn't find out why.

Comment: Try this: `printf "%s" "$(md5sum file | awk '{print $1}')" | wc -m`

Comment: It's worked! I try to understand how it work. As I know `printf "%s" "$(md5sum file | awk '{print $1}')"` or `printf "$(md5sum file | awk '{print $1}')"` don't print new line. I wonder why..  
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

Use awk's `length()` function:

```
md5sum file.png | awk '{print length($1)}'
32
```

---

It's because `awk` will add a line feed character to the output. You can check:

```
md5sum file.png | awk '{print $1}' | xxd
```

You can tell awk to not doing that using `ORS` *output record separator* variable:

```
md5sum file.png | awk '{print $1}' ORS='' | wc -m
32
```

Comment: You help me a lot. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Glad to see it helped.